# Java: What is the purpose of creating an object in the heap with no reference

Tags: java, object, garbage-collection, heap-memory

The code I came across was this, an object is created and it’s method was called:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       new DemoSoap().request();  //<----how come there is no reference?
    }



private void request() {
       try {
         // Build a SOAP message to send to an output stream.
         SOAPMessage msg = create_soap_message();

         // Inject the appropriate information into the message. 
         // In this case, only the (optional) message header is used
         // and the body is empty.
         SOAPEnvelope env = msg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
         SOAPHeader hdr = env.getHeader();

         // Add an element to the SOAP header. 
         Name lookup_name = create_qname(msg);
         hdr.addHeaderElement(lookup_name).addTextNode("time_request");

         // Simulate sending the SOAP message to a remote system by
         // writing it to a ByteArrayOutputStream.
         out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         msg.writeTo(out);

         trace("The sent SOAP message:", msg);

         SOAPMessage response = process_request();
         extract_contents_and_print(response);
       }
       catch(SOAPException e) { System.err.println(e); }
       catch(IOException e) { System.err.println(e); }
    }
```

- Will the object be destroyed by garbace collection after the
  request() method?
- what is the advantage of creating an object in the heap with no reference, as in this case?

Comment: If you think that this call is suspicious, you are right: calls like that often siggest that the method `request` should have been made `static`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Well, maybe `DemoSoap` can be optionally configured? That would not work so well with static methods. `new DemoSoap(nonStandardPort, ignoreSSLErrors).withFunkyOption(x).request()`

Comment: and maybe the code that creates and configures the `DemoSoap` instance (including choosing between `DemoSoap` and `TestSoap`) is not always the same code that calls `request`?

Answer (score 5):

The point is simply to be able to call the `request` method.

And yes, as soon as the statements ends, the object can be garbaged.

Note that in this code, as the object is initialized without parameters, unless there are other constructors or methods, it seems the method should have been made static : the instance seems totally useless.

Comment: What is the advantage of not having a reference to the object?

Comment: @Luther Why have a reference if you don't use it ?

Comment: @Luther: what is the advantage of having one if you don't use it? The advantage of not having one is that it avoids a useless variable, and reduces the scope of the object.

Comment: In a way I'm using the object just once, and I could have created a reference for that only access.

Comment: Yes you could, but if you don't use this instance past this call, the reference is useless. Don't add useless code.

Answer (score 2):

> Will the object be destroyed by garbace collection after the request() 
>   method?

Yes it will be GCd as soon as main method ends, the scope of the object is the main method's braces

> Why we create an object without a reference?

`request()` is a non-static method and we need an instance of the class `DemoSoap` to invoke that method. And if a code is just about invoking the method and doing nothing else with the created instance pf `DemoSoap`, then there is no point in having reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
new DemoSoap().request();
```

An object of `DemoSoap` is created and its method `request()` is invoked and the object is eligible for GC . The only purpose of instantiating that object was a one time call to `request()` , hence no need to keep a reference to that object for future. In your particular case I don't think it makes much difference.

But unecessary holding reference to an object which you don't need in future can be bad . Suppose ,

```
 void somemethod() {
   Demo demo = new Demo();
   demo.request(); // purpose of demo ends here .

   .......
   ........
   lots of processing in between
   .......
   // demo still refers to an object in heap uselessly .

}
```

**P.S.:** I have learnt that it is a good practice to release references as quickly as they can reasonably be released.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the object will be grbage collected after the scope (the `main()` method) is left.

Also in your case the complete program will end therefore there is no more need to handle objects after quiting the program.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the point is to call the `request()` method. You just cannot call it without an object instance.

In the general case, even a constructor can have useful side-effects (though that is certainly not an encouraged design choice), so you might want to call it even if you never use the instance at all.

For example

```
 new JdbcDriver();
```

registers the database driver into JDBC's global registry, so that it understands the connection strings for that driver (which it would not before you registered the driver by this trick or more "proper" means).

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you don't need the object anymore, you just want to call a method once.  Sometimes you need to create an object that instruments another object that runs as a thread